# How to create Lists of List in the following context

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

```
public class Person
{
public int Id{get;set;}
public string Name{get;set;}
}
public class Test
{

private readonly IPersonDataService _personDataService;
public Test(IPersonDataService personDataService)
{
_personDataService=personDataService;
}

List<Person> persons=_personDataService.GetList();
List<List<Person>> personLists=new <List<Person>>();
}
```

Imagine the `persons` list contains 50 items.I want to be able to extract 5                  lists of 10 items each from `persons` and add each list to `personLists`.
In the end the `personLists` should have 5 items where each item is a  List containing 10 items each.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list persons always has 50 items, you can do something like this:

```
for (int listCount = 0; listCount < 5; listCount++) {
 List<Person> newList = new List<Person>();
 personLists.add(newList);
 for (int innerCount = 0; innerCount < 10; innerCount++) {
  newList.add(persons.next());
 }
}
```

Keep in mind this is untested, but the general concept should be sound.